# Sentry Integration with FastApi

Tags: python, docker, nginx, fastapi, sentry

I have a FastApi application running locally on port 3000 on top of nginx reverse proxy port 80 so I can request localhost/api/v1/docs etc. I have also configured sentry locally and its running on port 9000.

Now I integrate sentry to FastApi using the below code:

```py
sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn="http://<key>@localhost:9000/2",

    # Set traces_sample_rate to 1.0 to capture 100%
    # of transactions for performance monitoring.
    # We recommend adjusting this value in production,
    traces_sample_rate=1.0,
)
```

In the FastApi logs, it is giving a warning:

> sentry_sdk.integrations.logging:sentry_patched_callhandlers:96 - Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f938851c250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /api/2/envelope/

I have no idea where I am doing wrong.

I am running 2 nginx docker containers 1 is for FastApi application, 2nd is by default comes with Sentry.

I have tried changing nginx port from 80 to 81 for FastApi but still same warning.

Comment: `localhost` refers to the internal network inside your FastAPI container - since the sentry container is running in a different container, you'll have to utilize docker's networking configuration to make them talk to each other (having them on the same network). If you're using docker-compose, the name given to the sentry container should automagically be available as the given hostname (i.e. `sentry` or something similar).

Comment: Thank you for your comment @MatsLindh . I have tried with web which is the name of sentry container but still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you assigned them the same, internal network name as well?

Comment: Now working after defining a network. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question but using the docker address for internal hosts would solve this issue without the use of a special setup network.

Using `host.docker.internal` this could be solved as follows.

`http://<key>@host.docker.internal:9000/2`

[Source](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host)